# Run bash command via PHP, change dir then execute binary

Tags: php, linux, bash, centos, centos6

So here's what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to start a binary under another user, via a PHP script. Apache has sudo access. The command works fine when ran via putty logged in as "test".

```
passthru('bash -c "sudo -u test cd /home/test/cs/ ; ./hlds_run"');
```

also might I add that

```
passthru('bash -c "sudo -u test ./home/test/cs/hlds_run"');
```

Won't work because of how the binary is written  (it won't find it's resources unless you cd to the folder before, tested on terminal)

Comment: You need to quote the command to `sudo` or the outer shell sees the `;` and splits the command first.

Comment: @EtanReisner Like this? passthru('bash -c "sudo -u test "cd /home/test/cs/ ; ./hlds_run" " '); ? Do I need to escape anything?

Comment: Yes, like that. And yes you need to escape the inner double quotes from the outer shell, yes.

Comment: passthru('bash -c "sudo -u test \"cd /home/test/cs/ ; ./hlds_run\" "'); no dice, it won't start. Edit:: I just realized php might escape the first \ so I tried  passthru('bash -c "sudo -u test \\"cd /home/test/cs/ ; ./hlds_run\\" "'); but still nope

Comment: Define "no dice" and "nope" more concretely please. What isn't working about this?

Comment: The process does not run. Let me try to get it to print the output instead of just FALSE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If everyone has access to `/home/test/cs`:

```
passthru('cd /home/test/cs && sudo -u test ./hlds_run');
```

If only the user `test` has access to the directory:

```
passhtru('sudo -u test sh -c "cd /home/test/cs && ./hlds_run"');
```

To arrive at the second invocation, you should already be familiar with `system` vs `execve` semantics (used by `passthru` and `sudo` respectively).

1. This is the tested shell string we need to run as a specific user:

   `cd /home/test/cs && ./hlds_run`
2. We can ensure that it always runs as a specific user with `sudo`, but `sudo` uses execve semantics. We have to convert our shell string to an `execve` array, and since this command A. relies on shell functionality like `cd` and B. does not include dynamic values, the best way to do this is to simply invoke a shell to interpret it verbatim:

   { `sh`, `-c`, `cd /home/test/cs && ./hlds_run` }
3. We can now apply `sudo` to run as our specific user:

   { `sudo`, `-u`, `test`, `sh`, `-c`, `cd /home/test/cs && ./hlds_run` }
4. `passthru` runs as a shell, so now we have to convert the `execve` array above back into a shell string, taking extreme care with quoting to ensure the shell will parse it into the exact argument list above. Fortunately this is a relatively simple case:

   `sudo -u test sh -c "cd /home/test/cs && ./hlds_run"`
5. We can now give it to `passthru`:

   `passthru('sudo -u test sh -c "cd /home/test/cs && ./hlds_run"');`

Comment: hail mary the second one works. Can you explain every bit of that command just for the sake of learning and not just having someone do it for me?

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this? (make sure if you have exec right for hlds_run)

```
passthru('bash -c "sudo -u test && /home/test/cs/hlds_run"');
```

Comment: OP mentions that the script can't be run directly like that and this fails to run the script under the sudo user.

Comment: The program can't run unless you use "cd" before and then run it while you're in the main folder. Doesn't sudo -u test cmd execute cmd via the user test? I'm not sure how it works but there's little to no documentation about it...

Comment: It's better if you can add the environment path to /home/test/cs/. So you can call direct to hlds_run without cd to the main folder.

Comment: The `cd` here isn't to find the binary. It is for the binary to find its data/etc. files it sounds like. So `$PATH` (assuming that's what you meant) isn't relevant here.

Comment: Maybe I'm explaining it wrong. What I mean is that , for example, if you log in on user and cd .. all the way to root and then ./home/test/cs/hlds_run it will start the process but it'll start spewing errors of not found components. If you cd .. all the way to root then cd /home/test/cs/ ; ./hlds_run it works fine.

Comment: Once you added /home/test/cs/ to the environment path, you can call the binary inside everywhere and the system will detect /home/test/cs/ which contain that binary as your working folder regardless of current path.